# How can I pass a path in PowerShell, I am getting an error that I can't figure out

Tags: powershell, path, winzip

This is one of my first powershell scripts and I can't make it work. I can't pass `"c:\"` as a destination folder.

My script:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Temp"
$winZipExe = "C:\Program Files\WinZip\WZUNZIP.EXE"
$destinationFolder = "c:\"
$passwordCommand

# Ask the user for a password
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Please enter the password for the .zipx files"
$passwordCommand = "-s" + $password.ToString()

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -Filter *.zipx | ForEach-Object {
    $zipxFile = $_.FullName
    $zipxFileName = $_.BaseName
    $outputFolder = (Resolve-Path $destinationFolder) ; $destinationFolder
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $outputFolder -Force
    & $winZipExe -e -d $passwordCommand $zipxFile #$outputFolder
}
```

My error:

```
c:\
New-Item : The path is not of a legal form.
At C:\Users\Nenad A. Dragic\Desktop\Unzip1.ps1:14 char:5
+     New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $outputFolder -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (C:\:String) [New-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

I have tested with this:
`$outputFolder = ""`

Done a lot of different arguments from Google, Stackoverflow and chatGPT, but can't make it work.

My zipx files contains a folder with the files in it and I would like it to unzip to `C:\`

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have permissions to write directly to C Drive. Try changing `$destinationFolder` to something depper. I.e. `C:\"YOUR_USERNAME"`.

Answer (score 0):

[Nawad-sama's answer offers a potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76051833/45375) - don't try to write directly to `C:\` - but let me address the error cause:

The error isn't caused by a lack of permissions (though you may run into permission issues later), it is caused by **an - ultimately inconsequential - bug in *Windows PowerShell***, which has since been fixed in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)

While **it never makes sense to try to create a drive's *root* directory** - if the drive is accessible, it by definition already has a root drive - the addition of the `-Force` switch to [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) `-ItemType Directory` should return information about the *existing* root drive (in the form of a [`System.IO.DirectoryInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.DirectoryInfo) instance; that is what now happens in PowerShell (Core) 7+).

Due to the bug, you get an obscure error message instead (`The path is not of a legal form.`)